TV show where main character can only see black and white
There was an interesting network TV show in the USA in the last ten years.  It was canceled during or after its first season.  It had something to do with law enforcement. The main character (possibly Michael Ealy?) could only see in black and white.  He might have had amnesia, and I think he doesn't remember who he is, but he currently has some great mental ability -- like either perfect memory (ironically) or computer-like reasoning & math abilities. Much of the show was dedicated to him figuring out who he was, where he came from, and why he was unusual in the ways he was unusual. It was really intriguing!
Any idea what the show was called?

This sounds like John Doe, which aired from 2002 to 2003, and is about a man who wakes up with amnesia, and uses his special abilities/knowledge to help solve crimes while being tracked by The Phoenix Organization.
From wikipedia:

I woke up in an island off the coast of Seattle. I didn't know how I got there ... or who I was. But I did seem to know everything else. There were things about me I didn't understand ... the brand, being colorblind, extreme claustrophobia. And while my gifts provided answers for others, I still search for my own. My name is John Doe.

and continues regarding his abilities:

However, apart from the details of his own past, "John Doe", as he comes to call himself, seems to have access to the sum total of all human knowledge: he knows how many dimples are on a golf ball, the population of Morocco, and other such obscure (and not-so-obscure) facts. He also has expert knowledge on everything from the stock market to computers. Over the course of the series John attempts to find clues about his past by using his unusual ability while also helping to solve crimes with the Seattle police department. In the process it becomes clear that an international conspiracy known as the Phoenix Organization is watching John's every move.

